# When is $1+a+a^2+\dotsb+a^{{\rm ord}_n(a)-1}$ divisible by $n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra

I posted this question on [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1175006/194169) 10 days ago and had no answer, comment or vote. If an answer is not available, I could really use a reference point as well.

For the sake of completeness, I am restating the essence of my question below, omitting details that can be found on the link above.

---

I am  interested in the following problem:

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define the function $S_n:\mathbb{Z_n^*}\to\mathbb{Z_n}$ by
  $$ S_n(\bar a) := \bar 1  + \bar a + \bar a^2 + ...+ \bar a^{\left(ord_n(a)\right)-1}, $$
where $\mathbb{Z_n^*}$ is the set of all invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z_n}$, and $ord_n(a)$ the order of $a$ modulo $n$.

Can a characterization for the sets 
  $$ A_n:=\{ \bar a \in \mathbb{Z_n^*} : S_n(\bar a) = \bar 0 \} $$

be found?

Now, considering the $\amalg {\mathbb{Z_n} }$ as consisting of the elements $(\bar a, n)$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and  $\bar a \in \mathbb{Z_n}$, we define the function  $S : \mathbb{N} \to \amalg {\mathbb{Z_n} } $ such as
\begin{align} S(n) = \left( \sum_{\bar a \in \mathbb{Z_n^*}} {S_n(\bar a)}, n \right)\end{align}
thinking of $S(n)$ as an element of $\mathbb{Z_n}$ when there is no danger of confusion.

This bring us to the second question. Can we find (or know more about) the set 
\begin{align} A:= \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : S(n) \in \mathbb{Z_n^*} \}\end{align}

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For the first question, isn't $S(a)=0$ for all $a\ne1$?

Comment: @AlexDegtyarev If n is prime, then yes, $S_n(a)=0$ for all $a\ne1$ . But if, lets say, $n=8$ then $S_n(3)=4$.

Comment: As a very basic observation, you have $S_n(\bar a)=0$ provided that both $a$ and $a-1$ are co-prime with $n$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a partial answer to your first question:

> A necessary condition for $S_n(\bar a)=0$ to hold is that $\gcd(a-1,n)\mid{\rm ord}_n(a)$; moreover, if $n$ is square-free, then this condition is also sufficient.

To see this, let $k:={\rm ord}_n(a)$ and $d:=\gcd(a-1,n)$, and write $a-1=db$ and $n=dm$. Then $S_n(\bar a)=0$ can be equivalently re-written as 
  $$ 1+a+\dotsc+a^{k-1}\equiv 0\pmod{dm}; \tag{$\ast$} $$
this yields $1+a+\dotsc+a^{k-1}\equiv 0\pmod d$, and necessity follows now by observing that $a\equiv 1\pmod d$, resulting in $1+a+\dotsc+a^{k-1}\equiv k\pmod d$.

This argument also shows that, conversely, $1+a+\dotsc+a^{k-1}\equiv 0\pmod{d}$ holds whenever $d\mid k$. Since $\gcd(d,m)=1$ for $n$ square-free, to prove sufficiency it suffices to show that for such $n$, we have $1+a+\dotsc+a^{k-1}\equiv 0\pmod{m}$. This is equivalent to $m\mid\frac{a^k-1}{db}$, or $dbm\mid a^k-1$, which further splits into the two conditions $db\mid a^k-1$ and $m\mid a^k-1$ in view of $\gcd(db,m)=1$ (following from $\gcd(d,m)=\gcd(b,m)=1$). Recalling that $db=a-1$ and and that $m\mid n$ and $k={\rm ord}_n(a)$, we see that, in fact, both $db\mid a^k-1$ and $m\mid a^k-1$ hold in a trivial way.